# When to validate form in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

I need to validate a field in my form by regular expression and I'm thinking when best to do it:

1. ***In the render method:*** It seems to be the most react way as I'll be keeping only the needed data in the state and calculating the derived data. But wouldn't it be bad for performance to run a regex on every render?

   ```
   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <input
           onChange={e => this.setState({ value: e.targe.value })}
           value={this.state.value}
         />
         Valid: {this.validate(this.state.value)}
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```
2. ***In the onChange handler:*** I could also validate the new value in the onChange handler and keep the validation result in the state. This way the regex will only be called when needed, but there will be redundant data in the state.

   ```
   render() {
     return (
       <div>
         <input
           onChange={e => this.setState({value:e.targe.value,valid:this.validate(e.target.value)}}
           value={this.state.value}
         />
         Valid: {this.state.valid}   
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```

Comment: Maybe you should try use Redux-Form to validate Form in quick way?

Comment: There's bound to be a wide range of opinions on this. In general though, you should IMO try to keep the state minimal, leading to making the validation calculated (e.g. in render, as you describe in the first option). There are various ways to optimize this, e.g. `_.memoize`.

Comment: First... if you looking for performance, don't use anonymous functions in onChange. This way, each call, a new function is created and executed. Instead create an function outside of the onChange and call this.

do `onChange={this.handleClick}`...
and define the function outside:
`handleChange = () => {
    this.setState({ value: e.targe.value })
  }`

The other Hand, you can put some delay into your handleChange function to prevent from changing state, if given delay not passed.

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/validate-react little plugin to manage simple validations

Answer (score 1):

You are better off doing it in change, i.e. your second approach. Reasons -

1. Its a better experience to not display errors right away until user has interacted with the form fields.
2. With controlled text fields, render will be invoked a lot of times. Any continuous validation will cause a noticeable perf drop eventually with either approaches. You can use debounced validations with the second approach to keep this under control.
3. Keeps business logic separate from `render`.

Comment: Flagging form field as "dirty" (for better UX) is a separate concern from validation. Making computation of the derived state effective is a separate concern from decision on whether some data should be stored in state or just derived. Business logic can be easily kept separate from `render` (method of a view component) while being effectively part of render (process), e.g. if computed in a Redux selector. So neither of your points actually supports the case of doing validation in change handler.

Comment: Validations are typically kicked off on user interactions, making them, as you succinctly put, "dirty". With the first approach, additional state will be needed to track that. And debouncing won't be feasible if you keep revalidating inside render. With redux, this question is moot as all business logic will be outside views.

Comment: First, keeping "dirty" flag (and similar) separate from validation has its own benefits. Second, perf. optimizations of the "in render" approach (in general) are a separate topic. _(You could for example calculate and store the derived state in a HoC and keep the view component pure. You could even debounce the calculation if you'd like to. I take the OP's code just as illustration - when I talk about "in render" approach, I mean the whole update process, including lifecycle methods, not just the `render` method itself.)_

Comment: Anyway, this question would find better home over at [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), as it's clearly subjective.

Comment: Agree on the subjective part, my response is more focused on his specific need as to me it appears that  the OP seems to know what he is doing and wants to pick an approach in that very context.